# extract data from varbinary compressed cell in mssql db

Tags: c#, sql-server, sharepoint, compression, varbinary

I have an MS Sql db which is connected to SharePoint 2010 content website. we have .pdf files in blob and meta info compressed with varbinary
(dbo.tCompressedBinary(varbinary(max), null)). Can anybody have any idea of how to do it ? 
In which format it will be decompressed?
Do I need T-SQL,CLR, C# code?